# java: Internal error in the mapping processor

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting this error for my MAP interface
java: Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.com.userapi.mapper.AddressMapperImpl     at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperRenderingProcessor.createSourceFile(MapperRenderingProcessor.java:59) at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperRenderingP

I have added @Componentscan and included MapStruct Interface package but while requesting endpoints it gives me 404